# Problems using form helpers in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, form-helpers

I have a class activity that has the follow atributes:

```
String type, Date date, String title
```

By including the associations it also has **user_id** and **place_id**.

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :place
```

In the other side **User has many activities** and **place has many activities**

So, the problem is when I want to create a new activity:
Scaffold creates the helper **_form** :

```
<%= form_for(@activity) do |f| %>
  <% if @activity.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@activity.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this activity from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @activity.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :place_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :place_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to receive the first 3 fields from the form (type, date and title) but to associate a user and a place I have to do other way. I need the user that is actual logged in and the place is choosen by tiping the name.

My idea to do this is the following:

**1)** The user issue, I can make a query by using the current_logged_user that I have acess and get his ID.

**2)** The place issue, I can use the name that I receive from form and query my Places table for the place with the name X and get the ID after.

But, because I don't know too much about rails, how can I do this? How can I use f.text_field and then made the query or whatever and use after in the controller?

Controller has already this stuff :

```
def create
    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
(...)

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_activity
      @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def activity_params
      params.require(:activity).permit(:type, :date, :title, :user_id, :place_id)
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structure your rails app to get neither the user_id nor the place_id directly from the form. Especially getting user_id from a submitted form is generally not a good idea. You usually do not want to whitelist `user_id` at all.

For **user_id**:

If you are using a gem like devise for user authentication, it gives you access to a method called `current_user`, which you can use to set the user_id from.

For **place_id**:

I suggest putting the activity as a sub route of place. e.g. instead of having the form under `<host>/activities/new`, put it under ``/places/:place_id/activities/new`. In your route file put the route as follows:

```
resources :places do
    resources :activities
end
```

Now, in your controller action you can do the following:

```
def create
    @activity = current_user.activities.new(activity_params)
    @activity.place_id = params[:place_id] (or even safer will be @activity.place = Place.find(params[:place_id], but this will require one more sql query ) 
    (...)
private      

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def activity_params
  params.require(:activity).permit(:type, :date, :title)
end
```

**UPDATE:**

If you absolutely want to have the form under /activities/new route then you can have a select tag for place_id in your form:

```
select_tag 'activity[place_id]', options_from_collection_for_select(Place.all, 'id', 'name')
```

This will create a selection with name 'activity[place_id]' (named this way for params.require(:activity).permit(place_id) ) and options looking like

```
<option value="1">Barcelona</option>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the idea of /places/:place_id/activities/new.Waht I'm going (and suposed) to do is /activities/new.

Thank you for the help @AOG

Comment: You're welcome. The idea is that associations can go under their parent's url to make both the url more informative and the backend coder's life easier. E.g. you can easily show things like "user activities related to a place".

Comment: I will see. Thank you once again!

Comment: I think I got the idea. Make a select with all the places in my database, right?

Comment: Yea, the first arg for options_from_collection_for_select is the input rails collection, the second is the method (here the id attribute) to use to generate values and the third is the method (here the name attribute) to use to generate option text. [Here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) is the API doc for it.